# InvokeMember where the member is an array property with reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

So I asked something similar last week, but I think it was pretty confusing, so Ill try to simplify it.

Say for instance I have a class that contains only properties like this:

```
public class MyPropertyClass
{
    public int IntegerProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Now suppose I have created another class with an array of `MyPropertyClass` like this:

```
public class AnotherPropertyClass
{
    public MyPropertyClass[] ArrayProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Now here is the complicated part.
I need to dynamically create a `MyPropertyClass[]` somehow. I've been trying it with a `List<object>` thus far. Then, make a call to `InvokeMember` with this array. Something like this:

```
//The list that I am adding elements to elsewhere in the code
List<object> objList = new List<object>();

//Adding a couple elements
objList.Add(new MyPropertyClass());
objList.Add(new MyPropertyClass());

//Create the parameter object array, has to be length one and contain an
//object array casted to MyPropertyClass or it will throw an exception.
object[] ob = new object[1] { objList.ToArray() };

//Instantiate the actual object I want to assign the array to.
object obj = new AnotherPropertyClass();

//The call to InvokeMember
obj.GetType().InvokeMember(
    "ArrayProperty",
    BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.SetProperty,
    Type.DefaultBinder,
    obj,
    ob);
```

This code will throw an exception. The problem is, objList.ToArray() creates an `object[]` and when InvokeMember tries to assign it to the `MyPropertyClass[]`, it complains about the type mismatch, even though all of the elements are `MyPropertyClass` types. Basically what I need is a way to say, "hey, all of the elements in objList.ToArray() are going to be `MyPropertyClass`" i.e object{MyPropertyClass[]} while letting the actual type be arbitrary, it might not be `MyPropertyClass`, it could be some other type, I don't know at compile time.

What I have here is only my attempt so far, if you know a different approach i'm all ears. If you want more information, see my old question here:

[runtime casting of an object[] to a custom type array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13883209/runtime-casting-of-an-object-to-a-custom-type-array)

I just think there is little too much extra stuff in there that's not related to the actual problem i'm having.

Comment: This doesn't even compile...

Comment: Changing `obj.InvokeMember` to `obj.GetType().InvokeMember` and the two `add()` methods to `Add()` will fix it.

Comment: @TrevorPilley I didn't copy and paste because my code is much more complicated than this sample. I assure you it will with a bit of fudging.

Comment: @Eve Thanks for pointing that out, i've updated it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an array of an unspecified type like this:

```
Array array = Array.CreateInstance(someType, someSize);
```

Comment: But what happens when I try to call InvokeMember with that variable?

Comment: @MattGrogan: It will work, since the variable will be of the correct type.

Comment: question about this method: It creates a 2D array?
Also, it doesn't work because when I call SetValue, it complains that it cant assign an Object to an array of this type (or something like that).

Comment: @MattGrogan: No; it creates a 1D array. See the docs.  Read the error message; it's telling you that you're putting in an object of the wrong type.

Comment: Got it. After a little trial and error, it works now, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You do it like this:

```
List<MyPropertyClass> objList = new List<MyPropertyClass>();
objList.Add(new MyPropertyClass());
objList.Add(new MyPropertyClass());

AnotherPropertyClass obj = new AnotherPropertyClass();

obj.GetType().GetProperty("ArrayProperty").SetValue(obj, objList.ToArray());
```

Comment: This throws an ArgumentException, remember that obj and objList are still just object types, I don't know at compile time that they are actually AnotherPropertyClass, it could very well be something else.